# A good PHP framework that is also scalable?

Tags: php, frameworks

I'm already into PHP and now I'm going to learn a new framework, because I am going to build a web platform that will be used by millions. So this obviously means I will need to scale it at some point of time and so with SO many options around me I'm just plain confused :| I read some articles on the web and I've come to a conclusion that Cake PHP and Symfony are good frameworks and are used by huge corporations. However, I am a little sceptical about the scaling part of these frameworks since I will be using AWS instances to host my project and it should be quite easy to scale. Thank You.

Comment: Your framework choice doesn't have much to do with scalability. You forgot to mention Zend Framework and Kohana. There is a lot of information about PHP frameworks on SO already.

Comment: good luck for the "millions unique" part

Comment: Agreed with "yes123". I've developed many apps for people that were supposed to be used by millions ;)

Comment: @yes123 - It is a current project for a client he needs me to rebuild his app from scratch, using a framework preferrably. He already has like say, 1-2 million views a month.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input. Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, scalability doesn't only depend on a developer. Well written framework gives you many options and ways to do things - that's what scalability is about. You can make it handle your personal webpage and big web application.

I would recommend Yii. I fall in love with this framework. It's really scalable, but you sometimes have to handle some things by yourself (which is good price for scalability and is a good insight on how it really works).

Comment: Thank You very much, Yii looks very promising. Gonna give it a shot. Ty.

Answer (score 4):

Scaling is mostly going to be handled by you, the developer, not the framework.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion all frameworks are pretty much the same when it comes to scaling.

Best is to google around and try to find if somebody has already done the heavy duty work to make one of those scale properly.

Even wordpress would scale the very same way of a frameworks. You problem is not to scale a framework but to scale LAMP. (database replication, caching, CDN etc)

Answer (score 1):

Scaling also depends on how your infrastructure is built out. Your code is part of it but if you don't have the capacity to run the code on decent hardware, your code will fail you.